# CSS overwrite by mobile media screen

Tags: css

I have this simple layout. Not sure why the media screen for mobile overwrite my main css. At laptop size, it shows orange color and at mobile size is show yellow color.

```css
  
/* main container */

#resume {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    background-color:silver;
}

  .parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
  

/****************
*      PHONE
****************/

@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
  #resume {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .display {
    max-width: 180px;
  }
  .child {
    flex: 100%;
    background-color:orange;
  }
  .topper {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <title>Steve</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resume">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child wider">
<header class="clear" id="header">
      <div>
        <h1 class="name">Steve</h1>
        <h2 class="label">Programmer</h2>
      </div><span class="location"><span class="address">2712 Broadway St,</span> <span class="postalCode">CA 94115,</span> <span class="city">San Francisco,</span> <span class="region">California</span> <span class="countryCode">US</span></span>
      <div id="contact">
        <div class="website">
          <span class="fa fa-external-link"></span> <a href="http://richardhendricks.com" target="_blank">http://richardhendricks.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span> <a href="mailto:richard@valley.com">richard@valley.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
          <span class="fa fa-mobile"></span> <a href="tel:(912)%20555-4321">(912) 555-4321</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="profiles">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="username">
            <span class="fa fa-twitter twitter social"></span> <span>neutralthoughts</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="username">
            <span class="fa fa-soundcloud soundcloud social"></span> <span class="url"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/dandymusicnl" target="_blank">dandymusicnl</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>        
      </div>
      <div class="child topper">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `min-width: 460px` means from `460px` up to infinity, lower the screen to see it lose effect, You probably want to reverse it to `max-width: 460px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CSS for mobile screen shall set MAX-width instead of min-width. Try:

```
     @media screen and (max-width: 460px)
```

The above CSS applies when the screen is narrower than 460px.

Comment: should I put both min and max also?

Answer (score 1):

Because both your code works on desktop and you `media` query is under in the file so it's executed after

Try this one

```css
/* main container */


/****************
*      PHONE
****************/

  #resume {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .display {
    max-width: 180px;
  }
  .child {
    flex: 100%;
    background-color:orange;
  }
  .topper {
    order: -1;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  #resume {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    background-color: silver;
  }
  .parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <title>Steve</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resume">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child wider">
        <header class="clear" id="header">
          <div>
            <h1 class="name">Steve</h1>
            <h2 class="label">Programmer</h2>
          </div><span class="location"><span class="address">2712 Broadway St,</span> <span class="postalCode">CA 94115,</span> <span class="city">San Francisco,</span> <span class="region">California</span> <span class="countryCode">US</span></span>
          <div id="contact">
            <div class="website">
              <span class="fa fa-external-link"></span> <a href="http://richardhendricks.com" target="_blank">http://richardhendricks.com</a>
            </div>
            <div class="email">
              <span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span> <a href="mailto:richard@valley.com">richard@valley.com</a>
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
              <span class="fa fa-mobile"></span> <a href="tel:(912)%20555-4321">(912) 555-4321</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="profiles">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="username">
                <span class="fa fa-twitter twitter social"></span> <span>neutralthoughts</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="username">
                <span class="fa fa-soundcloud soundcloud social"></span> <span class="url"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/dandymusicnl" target="_blank">dandymusicnl</a></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="child topper">
        2
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```